# Sorting custom container

Tags: c++

As part of my homework assignment I had to implement a container similar to std::Map.

After implementing the map I tried to sort it using std:sort but key.

```
std::sort(connectedFans.begin(), connectedFans.end());
```

Where connectedFans is:

```
Map<int, shared_ptr<Fan> >.
```

However I'm getting the following errors:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:3752:90: error: no type named
      'value_type' in 'std::__1::iterator_traits<mtm::Map<int, std::__1::shared_ptr<mtm::Fan> >::iterator>'
    _VSTD::sort(__first, __last, __less<typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::value_type>());
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
FanBookServer.cpp:50:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::sort<mtm::Map<int,
      std::__1::shared_ptr<mtm::Fan> >::iterator>' requested here
        std::sort(connectedFans.begin(), connectedFans.end());
        ^
1 error generated.
```

I think the problem is within my implementation of Map however I'm not sure where to look.
What should I do to my map for the std:sort algorithm to work on it?

Also, how can I make my Map to be usable with std:sort(iterator.begin(), iterator.end(), compareFunction)?

**[EDIT]
Bellow is my Map.h**
http://pastebin.com/rACeK5av

Comment: Can you show us your class?

Comment: It is not the exactly the problem, but I think is a valid test: Did you first test with a `std::map` to garantee that 'Fan' object is sortable (i.e., implements `operator<` correctly)?

Comment: @wesley.mesquita, The problem is that my map hold shared_ptr<Fan> and not Fan and I'm not sure how to handle this.

Comment: @Doppelganger for this specific problem, you can implement a custom compare function. For instance, if you are at a C++11, use a lambda expression like `std::sort(connectedFans.begin(), connectedFans.end(), [&](std::shared_ptr<Fan> fanA, std::shared_ptr<Fan> fanB) {return *fanA < *fanB;}`. If you are not @ a C++11 env, look for std::function.

Comment: @wesley.mesquita I think this will work, thanks!
You can post this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your specific issue of using `shared_ptr` in your container, you can implement a custom compare function.

For instance, if you are at a C++11, use a lambda expression like `std::sort(connectedFans.begin(), connectedFans.end(), [&](std::shared_ptr<Fan> fanA, std::shared_ptr<Fan> fanB) {return *fanA < *fanB;}`. If you are not @ a C++11 env, look for std::function.